An interface declaring no members is equivalent to its supertype. @typescript-eslint/no-empty-object-type
I built a nextjs project, facing an error when want to deploy it to vercel.like below:
./components/ui/input.tsx
6:18  Error: An interface declaring no members is equivalent to its supertype.  @typescript-eslint/no-empty-object-type

I use google and chatgpt to try many method but still failed, such as :
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
or
add rules below :
{
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface": "off"
  }
}

both unavailablbe.
the error is in the page below, any one can help will be high appreciated.
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface */
import * as React from "react"

import { cn } from "@/lib/utils"

export interface InputProps extends React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {}

const Input = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputProps>(
  ({ className, type, ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
      <input
        type={type}
        className={cn(
          "flex h-9 w-full rounded-md border border-input bg-transparent px-3 py-1 text-sm shadow-sm transition-colors file:border-0 file:bg-transparent file:text-sm file:font-medium file:text-foreground placeholder:text-muted-foreground focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-1 focus-visible:ring-ring disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50",
          className
        )}
        ref={ref}
        {...props}
      />
    )
  }
)
Input.displayName = "Input"

export { Input }


You can change on
export interface InputProps extends React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {}

to
export type InputProps = React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>


it works, thanks

worked for me as well thanks buddy

@Thoxh YanZhang your welcome

Go to the .eslintrc.json file and configure it like this:
{
  "extends": ["next/core-web-vitals", "next/typescript"],
  "rules": { "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-object-type": "off" }
}

in order to turn off the offending rule.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

It is mentioned in the Next.js documentation here: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/eslint#disabling-rules

i fixed it adding this to the rules object
"@typescript-eslint/no-empty-object-type": "off"

You can add the following to your .eslintignore file to fix the issue:
/components/ui/**.tsx

This will exclude all .tsx files in the components/ui directory from linting.
